# How to create a multiple windows/views on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to create multiple view or window in a (Window based) iPhone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes kind of possible. Just create a new view using a view controller and create an instance of that view in your class. Then in an ibaction you could do some removing and adding subviews. That's just a quick and easy way tho, you can get into a lot more detail with how you would manage each view, etc.

**Edit on Request:**
In your class, you would create an instance of it in the interface like so:

```
MyClass *myClass; (make sure to alloc and init in the init or awakeFromNib method)
```

Then make an instance of the app delegate in the ibaction like this:

```
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And then you can do this to switch from one view to another:

```
[self removeFromSuperView]; (or self.view in case this is a view controller)
[[myAppDelegate window] addSubview:myClass];
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. can u give me some example or sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following to add a view programatically:

```
     //If you create controllers via XCode, just link them in the .h file with IBOutlet
     UIViewController *aViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     self.viewController = aViewController;
     [aViewController release];
     // Add the view controller's view as a subview of the window
     UIView *controllersView = [viewController view];
     [window addSubview:controllersView];
     [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```